# How I can post my four kind of post with prioritizing it.

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I'm working on a project, using Django 2.06. I have four model to maintain four kinds of posts from users and have to show it on one page.

```
 class QuickWordView(ListView):
     template_name = "index.html"
     queryset = QuickWord.objects.all()
     context_object_name = 'quickword'

def get_context_data(self, **Kwargs):
    context = super(QuickWordView, self).get_context_data(**Kwargs)
    thought = QuickWord.objects.all()
    add_product = AddProduct.objects.all()
    article = Article.objects.all()
    official_letter = OfficalLetter.objects.all()
    context['addproduct'] = add_product
    context['article_view'] = article
    context['official_letter'] = official_letter
    return context
```

Ps: sorry for spacing

at the template section, I used four For tags to show the user post. Now, i want to show with priority such as I have add product, article, letter model. if I post an article it loop through at the article section to the template.

**such as**

shohan Ceo

Article
General It Is Unclear Whether
The federal government has quietly revived its investigation into the murder of Emmett Till, the 14-year-old African-American boy whose abduction and ...

Keep it
2 hours ago
shohan Ceo

Article
General It Is Unclear Whether
The federal government has quietly revived its investigation into the murder of Emmett Till, the 14-year-old African-American boy whose abduction and ...

Keep it
2 hours ago
shohan Ceo, Hubblelook

Article
General Although Two White
Emmett was from Chicago and had been visiting relatives in the Mississippi Delta when he went into a store and encountered one of its owners, ...

*Notice that all posted articles are posted one after another*.

Template:

```
{% for article in article_view %} <!-- article card -->
        {% autoescape off %}
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">
            <div>
              <span class="right floated"> {{ 
              article.article_pub_time|naturaltime }} </span>
              <p>{{ user.username }} <span class="meta"> Ceo, Hubblelook 
           </span> </p>
            </div>
            <div class="meta">
              Article
            </div>
            <a
              class="header"
              href="{% url 'details' article.id article.slug %}"
              style="text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;" >
              <span class="font-italic"> {{ article.Initial_keyword_choices 
            }}</span> {{ article.title|title }}
            </a>
            <p
              style='color: black;'>
              {{ article.description|capfirst|truncatewords:25 }}
            </p>

            <div class="extra">
              Keep it
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui section divider"></div>
       {% endautoescape %}
      {% endfor %}
```

same thing happens for other posts too. I want to show it like if I post an article it will show, after that, if I post a letter it will show after that article I just posted.

How I can solve this problem... Do I have to work on template tags or at the view section.

Thank you

Comment: You probably should not work with four models. Can't you just add some flags to the `Post` model that specify what kind of `Post` it is?

Comment: This will easily get out of hand. Imagine that you have 20 types of posts, and you define one more. Than you would have to rewrite all locations where you used those models